# Low hashrate with Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti

Tags: mining, mining-pools, nvidia

I just set up a cheap mining rig running Ubuntu server 18.04 and using Nanominer, which I have been using for Monero.

Now I installed an Asus Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti using a Riser pci-1X to pci16X adapter to start mining Ethereum, allegedly, with this GPU I should be getting something around 15 MH/s, but I only get roughly 3 MH/s.

Something to note is that the CPU I got in this motherboard is a Intel Celeron J1800 and I wonder if this could be such a dramatic bottleneck that significantly decreases GPU performance, or is it that I need to downgrade the drivers as I've seen as a solution in some other forums.

Thank very much every one!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try a different miner. I suggest Claymore.
[Download from here](https://claymoredualminer.com/)

That solved my case.

Comment: Actually after some more investigation, this GPU, simply does not' have enough power fo Ethereum, so now I'm mining Ravencoin with it and goin just fine.

Comment: Yes, recently the Ethereum DAG size increase to make 4GB GPUs obsolete.